# HAC Standard Errors for OLS Regression in Python

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels, standard-error, autocorrelation

I have high autocorrelation in my dataset so I want to calculate HAC standard errors for the regression. I aim to use the standard error to calculate a confidence interval on my output prediction later.

I have been using following code but it only gives me SE for coefficients and not overall regression

```
reg = smf.ols('y ~ 1 + x',data=df).fit(cov_type='HAC',cov_kwds={'maxlags':1})
```

I have used following code to get SE for regression but the value are the same for regular OLS and Newey-West estimator. Any suggestions on how to identify robust standard errors for regression output?

```
np.sqrt(reg.mse_resid)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your want. Sandwich standard errors only correct the standard errors and covariance of the parameter estimates. They do NOT change the parameter estimates, and therefore not any results statistics like residual standard deviation.

Comment: Can they correct standard errors of regression (not just parameters)?

Imagine function y= b_0 + b_1 * x + e 
y is endogenous and x is exogenous

How do I get HAC standard errors for y (not b_0 or b_1)?

Comment: Standard errors for predicted mean `y_hat = x * b_hat` will use HAC se through b_hat. But  standard error for y just depends on residual se. There is no function that would correct residual se or variance, outside of time series analysis.

Comment: Ok! When autocorrelation is high, is SE for y_hat still underestimated? Or does that just apply to b_hat? 

If SE y_hat is wrong due to autocorrelation (Durbin Watson=0.5), how do you best adjust for it? Instead of just adding more variables that can capture serial correlation